# Mule ESB - Get payload value

Tags: mule

I'm not able to get the ID from the query result.
Mule version is 3.5.
This is the flow:

```
<flow name="mule.activity">
<poll doc:name="Poll">
<fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10000"/>
<db:select config-ref="JSDB" doc:name="Database">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT ID FROM ACTIVITY where rownum = 1]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
</poll>
<logger message="Current payload is #[payload]" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger message="Current payload size is #[payload.size()]" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger message="Current id is #[payload.ID]" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

And this is the log

```
[2015-03-18 13:13:36,875] DEBUG: Current payload is [{ID=1363230}]
[2015-03-18 13:13:36,881] DEBUG: Current payload size is 1
[2015-03-18 13:13:36,888] DEBUG: id is null
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returning payload of a query with the DB connector is always a list, whether is 0,1, or n elements.
Your MEL expression is assuming it's a map: #[payload.ID]
You should do something like #[payload.get(0).ID]

Then again I would advice you no to use this form to accessing maps

## [payload.get(0).ID]

But rather

## [payload.get(0)['ID']]

In the first example if you make a mistake with the id of the map you're trying to access the error isn't always that descriptive.

HTH

Comment: Thanks ... now it works. How can I iterate over a query result with more than one row?

Comment: Check out the for each scope docs http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Foreach